# Не знаю как правильно спозиционировать блоки

Tags: html, css

Есть такой блок, который не знаю как правильно сверстать.
Верстка без бутстрапа (но адаптивная). Самая левая и правая граница направляющих - это ширина контейнера. Блок с текстом выровнен по левому краю контейнера, но картинка вылезает на контейнер и приклеена к правому краю браузера.

Если блок с картинкой абсолютно спозиционировать, и задать right: 0;
то я не смогу задать ей максимальную ширину в 400px (как в макете), и что бы при сжатии браузера, блок с картинкой должен уменьшатся (обрезаться правый край)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> Если блок с картинкой абсолютно спозиционировать

Не совсем хороший вариант, потому что потом при адаптивности перестроить блоки будет тяжелее.

**display:flex и flex-wrap:wrap** дадут возможность перестроить блоки лучше, при меньшем коде. Всего лишь указав дочерним элементам другое значение ширины.

Как пример: https://jsfiddle.net/wv6bajn1/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  width:800px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.some-block{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.some-block p{
  display:block;
  width:50%;
}
.some-block img{
  display:block;
  width:50%;
  height:300px;
}

@media (max-width:480px){
    .some-block p{
         width:100%;
    }
    .some-block img{
         width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="some-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="some-block">
            <p>Есть такой блок, который не знаю как правильно сверстать.
                Верстка без бутстрапа (но адаптивная). Самая левая и правая граница направляющих - это ширина контейнера.
                Блок с текстом выровнен по левому краю контейнера, но картинка вылезает на контейнер и приклеена к правому краю браузера.</p>
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

section:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #F48124 url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/33109/fall-autumn-red-season.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  /*background-size: cover;*/
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <p>Есть такой блок, который не знаю как правильно сверстать. Верстка без бутстрапа (но адаптивная). Самая левая и правая граница направляющих - это ширина контейнера. Блок с текстом выровнен по левому краю контейнера, но картинка вылезает на контейнер
          и приклеена к правому краю браузера.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```